# Having problems with cx_Freeze and making an executable

Tags: python-3.x, executable, cx-freeze, recursionerror

I've written a Python script that I need to make into a stand alone executable. I'm trying to use cx_Freeze, but I keep getting recursion errors. I've seen that this question has been asked before, but none of the solutions I could find seem to work for my situation.
My script is importing the following libraries:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import itertools
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

I've tried making the executable with two different setup scripts. Here they are:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
build_exe_options={
    'excludes':[],
'zip_includes_packages':['tkinter', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'PIL'],}
setup(name='script', version='1.0', description='', executables=[Executable('C:/Temp/Name/.spyder-py3/file.py')])
```

This is the other setup I have tried:

```
import cx_Freeze, sys
base=None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
   base='Win32GUI'
executables = [cx_Freeze.Execuatble('C:/Temp/Name/.spyder-py3/file.py', base=base)]
cx_Freeze.setup(name='script', options={'build_exe':{'packages':['tkinter', 'itertools', 'datetime', 'PIL'],'includ_files':['C:/Temp/Name/.spyder-py3/image.png']}},
version='1.0',
description='',
execuatables=executables)
```

For both setups, when I run the following command in the Anaconda prompt

```
python c:/Temp/Name/.spyder-py3/file.py build
```

I get this error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
```

I've looked for solutions on this site and many others, but I can't find any reference to `__instancecheck__.` Does anyone know what that is? And is there something wrong in my setup scripts?